# Como cambio la direccion que se abre un SearcView en android studio?

Tags: java, xml, searchview

tengo una consulta , tengo un SearchView en un toolBar pero normalmente este se abre de izquierda a derecha por default, y claro el icono que viene incluido en el mismo SearchView esta situado en el lado izquierdo tambien , pero yo quiero que este SearchView se abra de derecha a izquierda , porque quiero poner el SearchView en la parte superior derecha de mi pantalla cosa que si presiono el Icono de buscar se me abra de derecha a izquierda ,. ya que actualmente si posiciono el SearchView en la parte superior derecha de mi pantalla y con su expasion por default q tiene al presionar el icono no veria el campo para poder escribir.

mi xml que tengo es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_70"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:background="@color/color_sbc_mostaza"
>

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/reservas"/>


 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_300"
       />
```

en el java no tengo nada todo esta por default.

muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que quieres es esto:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" //debes manejar la ubicación de esta manera
    />
```

En tu caso:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_300" //le estas diciendo que se ubique a la izquierda
   />
```